# Don't display duplicate column data from Matrix

Tags: matrix

If I have a matrix field with data like

```
Mon    X    Y
Mon    A    B
Tue    X    Y
Wed    X    Y
Wed    A    B
```

how can I output that on the front-end so that it looks like

```
Mon    Tue    Wed    
X Y    X Y    X Y
A B           A B
```

At the moment I'm getting

```
Mon    Mon    Tue    Wed    Wed    
X Y    A B    X Y    X Y    A B
```

Comment: I guess it would be easiest done with css, something like 
div.day[Mon]:nth-child(n+1) { display:none; }

Comment: I've updated the desired output. I'm not sure I can achieve that with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a good use for stash. Capture the matrix (or the entire entry, it's up to you). The following assumes you know how to capure and set a list with stash, ie:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="matrix_block"}         
<!-- Capture the matrix to a list -->
    {matrix_field}
        {stash:day}{day}{/stash:day} <!-- The day -->
        {stash:col_1}{event_1}{/stash:col_1} <!-- Value 1 -->
        {stash:col_2}{event_2}{/stash:col_2}
    {/matrix_field}
{/exp:stash:set_list}




<!-- Now we have a list, duplicate it and create new list using only the days -->
{exp:stash:split_list 
    name="daysofweek"
    list="matrix_block"
    match="#[a-zA-Z]#"
    against="day"
}

<!-- Now out put the sucker -->
{exp:stash:parse} <!-- Make sure everything else is set before trying to target data -->

{exp:stash:get_list name="daysofweek" unique="day" require_prefix="yes" prefix="out" } <!-- 
    Get the days from our duplicated list, using unique="" makes sure we dont get duplicate days,
    force prefix so inner get_list doesn't bork -->

    <li>{out:day} <!-- The unique day -->

        {exp:stash:get_list:sub name="matrix_block" match="#^{out:day}$#" against="day" parse="inward" }<!--
            Get the full list, match the contents 'day' against the day in this list -->

            <ul>
                <li>{col_1} {col_2}</li>
            </ul>
        {/exp:stash:get_list:sub}

    </li>

{/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Mae sure your Stash is up-to-date. Tested locally with hard coded list and works fine.

**Update**:
`stash:get_list:sub` is used when you're inside a get_list already. I used sub but could be elephant.

'raw' refers to the initial set_list name, updated code I mistakenly used raw instead of matrix_block

Comment: The headings are coming out OK but I'm not getting any of the other data. I've never come across the `exp:stash:get_list:sub` tag before. Is it documented anywhere? And what does the `name` *raw* refer to?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Needed a prefix on the sub list but all good now, thanks :)